# Unexpectedly able to call derived-class virtual function from base class ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, pure-virtual, stdthread

Can anyone help explain this unexpected behavior?

**The Premise**

I've created class Thread that contains a member `std::thread` variable. Thread's ctor constructs the member `std::thread` providing a pointer to a static function that calls a pure virtual function (to be implemented by base classes).

**The Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

namespace
{

class Thread
{
public:
    Thread()
        : mThread(ThreadStart, this)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; // This line commented later in the question.
    }

    virtual ~Thread() { }

    static void ThreadStart(void* pObj)
    {
        ((Thread*)pObj)->Run();
    }

    void join()
    {
        mThread.join();
    }

    virtual void Run() = 0;

protected:
    std::thread mThread;
};

class Verbose
{
public:
    Verbose(int i) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i << std::endl; }
    ~Verbose() { }
};

class A : public Thread
{
public:
    A(int i)
        : Thread()
        , mV(i)
    { }

    virtual ~A() { }

    virtual void Run()
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

protected:
    Verbose mV;
};

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a(42);
    a.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**The Problem**

As you may have already noticed, there's a subtle bug here: `Thread::ThreadStart(...)` is called from the `Thread` ctor context, therefore calling a pure/virtual function will not call the derived class' implementation. This is borne out by the runtime error:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

**However**, there is unexpected runtime behavior if I remove the call to `std::cout` in the `Thread` ctor:

```
virtual void {anonymous}::A::Run(){anonymous}::Verbose::Verbose(int): : 042

virtual void {anonymous}::A::Run(): 1
virtual void {anonymous}::A::Run(): 2
virtual void {anonymous}::A::Run(): 3
virtual void {anonymous}::A::Run(): 4
```

I.e. removing the call to `std::cout` in the `Thread` ctor seems to have the effect of being able to call a derived class' pure/virtual function from the base class` constructor context! This doesn't align with prior learning and experience.

Build environment in Cygwin x64 on Windows 10. gcc version is:

```
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm baffled by this observation and am burning with curiosity about what's going on. Can anyone shed light?

Comment: Nothing unexpected here. When the object is only constructed as far as any specific base class A, the only virtual function implementations available are those visible from A.

Comment: It's a shame we do not have a post-ctor in addition. Would be so useful here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior of this program is undefined, due to race condition.

But, if you want to reason about it, let's try.

For `A`'s construction, here's what happens:

1. `mThread` is initialized. The OS schedules it to start at some point in the future.
2. `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;` - this is a fairly slow operation from the program's perspective.
3. `A` constructor runs - initializing its *vtable* (this is not mandated by the stanard, but as far as I know, all implementations do this).

   *If this happens before `mThread` is scheduled to start, you get the behaviour you observed.* Otherwise, you get the pure virtual call.

Because those operations aren't in any way sequenced, the behaviour is undefined.

You can notice that you removed a fairly slow operation from your base's constructor, thus initializing your derived - and its vtable - much faster. Say, before the OS actually scheduled `mThread`'s thread to start. That being said, this did not fix the problem, just made encountering it less likely.

If you modify your example a bit, you'll notice that removing the IO code made the race harder to find, but fixed nothing.

```
virtual void Run()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i << std::endl;
//      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    A a(42);
    a.join();
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wQgz4kiDr4dekEZ5)

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: If I understand you correctly: if `Thread` has no `cout`, it initializes quickly, therefore its vtable _may_ be initialized before the OS schedules the `std::thread`, and if so, by the time the `std::thread` invokes `ThreadStart`, the vtable entry for `Run()` will be populated, thereby invoking `A::Run()`. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: @StoneThrow yeah.

Comment: @krzaq: Thank you; that was a great explanation. So I was actually mistaken when I said `ThreadStart()` is called from the `Thread` ctor context. It's actually called in a separate context: that of the spawned `std::thread`.